# Is it Safe to dual boot windows 10 and ubuntu in single ssd?

Tags: 18.04, dual-boot, windows-10

I have ssd 240gb , i want dual boot with shrink 60gb from windows , is it safe for my windows cause i dont want file in windows is damaged . I just need ssd just for fast system file and os  and some neccesary file, big file i save to external hdd. Can some one suggest me what i supposed to do.

Comment: Use only Windows tools/programs to shrink Windows.  Leave Windows partition with enough free space(more than 20%).  Recommended to backup data when adjusting partition size or installing another OS.  OOPs happen.

Comment: See also: Shows installer with screen shots. Both BIOS purple accessibility screen & UEFI black grub menu screen
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI
Also shows Windows 10 screens or similar to Windows 8
https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Answer (score 0):

Windows files will not be damaged. The most common way that happens is when people mount the C: drive and accidentally delete windows system files as they are visible in Ubuntu even if they are not in Windows.

1. Before you install, make sure you shrink your partition using Windows. You can use Disk Management, Diskpart or a 3rd party app for this.
2. During install, select "*Install Alongside Windows*" option. This will automatically detect and install Ubuntu in the free space.
3. Finish the installation and you are done.

This does not usually run into issues but it is always safe to **have a backup of important data.**